# Remove a number string from a text file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a file with a list of names and phone numbers as follows:

```
Smith,John 315-555-1212
Jones,Graham 315-234-2344
Aikman,Troy 312-153-3232
Young,Steve 415-343-3421
```

I need a command string that will output just the lines with "315" area code, output the line without the area code and sort according to last name. i would like the output to look like this:

Jones,Graham 234-2344

Smith,John 555-1212

So far I have this for getting the list. "areacode" is the name of my file. How can I print the sorted list of names and remove the area code from my list of names in the output?

```
awk '$2~/315/ { print }' areacode
```

Comment: I'm no ninja when it comes to shell but this should work: sort "areacode" | grep 315\- | sed 's|315\-||'

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what the output should look like in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep  ' 315-' areacode |  awk  '{ sub(/315-/ ,"" ); print $0}' | sort -t, -k1 > newfile
```

Try that for a start, assuming I got what you asked.  This (except the sort ) done all in awk as well.

```
awk '/315-'/ { sub(/315-/ ,"" ); print $0 } ' areacode | sort -t, -k1 > newfile
```

Comment: You `awk` is wrong.  You need the space before `315` and you have the single quote wrong. `awk '/ 315-/ { sub(/315-/ ,"" ); print $0 } ' areacode`

Comment: hi - i get following error.  never used sub command so not sure what the correct syntax is  :   error below
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{sub(/'

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk '/ 315-/ {sub(/315-/ ,"");print|sort}' sort="sort -t, -k1" areacode 
Jones,Graham 234-2344
Smith,John 555-1212
```

Answer (score 0):

try as below...you can pass the areacode which you are searching as parameter...

```
 awk '$2 ~ "^"areacode {split($2,a,"-"); print $1" "a[2]"-"a[3]}' areacode=315 myfile.txt | sort -t, -k2
```

sample output when area 315 is passed

```
Jones,Graham 234-2344
Smith,John 555-1212
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -F'[ ,-]' '$3==315 { a[$2]=$1 } END { n=asorti(a,b); for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print b[i],a[b[i]] }' file
```

Split the line into fields on space, comma or hyphen. Populate an array `a` whose keys are the surnames and values are the forenames. After processing the file, sort on the array keys and loop through the sorted array.

Using awk and sort:

```
awk -F'[ ,-]' '$3==315 { print $2,$1 }' file | sort -k2
```

Print the forename followed by the surname and sort alphabetically on the surname.

Output, using either approach:

```
Graham Jones
John Smith
```

If you want to keep the original "surname,forename" format, you could instead use (GNU awk):

```
awk -F'[ ,]' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } $3 ~ /^315/ { a[$2]=$1 } END { n=asorti(a,b); for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print a[b[i]],b[i] }' file
```

Or:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^315/ { print $1 }' file | sort -t, -k1
```

Output:

```
Jones,Graham
Smith,John
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort -t, -k2 file | awk -v area="315" 'sub("^"area"-","",$2)'
Jones,Graham 234-2344
Smith,John 555-1212
```

or if you only want the names:

```
$ sort -t, -k2 file | awk -v area="315" '$2 ~ "^"area{print $1}'
Jones,Graham
Smith,John
```

Comment: get an error awk: syntax error near line 1 for your first part. the output you have is exactly what i need not sure what the issue is. thanks

Comment: You are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Never use that awk as it is, well, old and broken. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead, unless you can install GNU awk (gawk) as that is far superior to all of the other awks.